# How to select 2 tables without join and using difference WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

```
Table t1:     Table t2:
+----+----+  +----+----+
| i1 | i2 |  | d1 | d2 |
+----+----+  +----+----+
| 1  | a  |  | 6  | k  |
| 2  | b  |  | 7  | y  |
| 3  | c  |  | 8  | z  |
+----+----+  +----+----+
```

How to select 2 tables without `join` and using difference WHERE clause?
I have tried :

```
SELECT i.1, i.2, d.1, d.2
FROM tbl_t1, tbl_t2
WHERE i.1 = 2 AND d.1 = 8
```

It show wrong result. Any idea?
I want show result as following :

```
2 == b
8 == z
```

Comment: What is the expected result you want?

Comment: ok i have update expected result on my question. Please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION, which joins vertically and not like join horizontally

```
SELECT i.i1, i.i2
FROM tbl_t1
WHERE i.i1 = 2 
UNION ALL
SELECT
 d.d1, d.d2 
FROM tbl_t2 d
WHERE  d.d1 = 8
```

Comment: Sorry I forget mention my code can't split into two SELECT.

`$aColumns = array( 'i.i1', 'i.i2', 'd.d1', 'd.d2' )

$print_query = $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))." FROM   $sTable $sWhere";`

Comment: Perhaps using method suggested by someone just now i don't know why he deleted his answer ... `Select (concat_ws('', t1.i1, t2.d1) * 1) as col1, concat_ws('', t1.i2, t2.d2) as col2 from tbl_t1 t1, tbl_t2 T2 where t1.i1=2 AND t2.d1=8`

Comment: from your code `tbl_t2cd` is spelling error? or 'cd' is syntac?

Comment: your code looks like it can be used for sql injection, but your code is too small to guess. code that @amsh wrote works to show them horizontally, so give it a try

Comment: @zac1987 `Sorry I forget mention my code can't split into two SELECT` I don't understand this limitation, but if it's important, then I suggest you edit the question accordingly.